# Multidimensional array sum values

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have following function to sum multidimensional array values.

```
// summing values of multidimensional array
function getSum($array, $path = array()){
    // process second argument:
    foreach ($path as $key) {
        if (!is_array($array) || !isset($array[$key])) {
            return 0; // key does not exist, return 0
        }
        $array = $array[$key];
    }
    if(is_array($array)) {
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            $sum += $value;
        }
    } else{
        $sum = $array;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

I'm using the function like this:

```
$array = array();
$array['one']['green'][20] = 20;
$array['one']['blue'][20] = 5;
$array['one']['blue'][30] = 10;

getSum($array,['one','green']); // 20
getSum($array,['one','blue',20]); // 5
```

Now I have a problem if I don't want to for example set any spesific color because I want that script sums all values from category 20 from all colours.

So it should be working like this:

```
getSum($array,['one','*',20]); // 25
```

Thanks for your help!

Here is example of my array:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [AREA I] => Array (
            [20] => 1 
            [25] => 0 
            [30] => 0 ) 
        [AREA II] => Array ( 
            [20] => 0 
            [30] => 0 ) 
        [AREA III] => Array ( 
            [20] => 2 
            [30] => 0 ) 
        [AREA IV] => Array ( 
            [20] => 0 
            [30] => 3 ) 
        [AREA V] => Array ( 
            [20] => 4 
            [25] => 0 
            [30] => 3 )  
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [AREA I] => Array ( 
            [20] => 0 
            [30] => 0 ) 
        [AREA II] => Array ( 
            [20] => 0 
            [30] => 0 ) 
    )
)
```

And here is example of my `getSum` call:

```
getSum($visitsandinfosact,['*','*',20]); // should print 7
```

Comment: such array `$array['one'] = 10;
$array['one']['green'] = 20;` cant exist. Either `$array['one']` is array or it's scalar value

Comment: @splash58: I edited my code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Recursive Function

I was not sure if `['one','*']` should give 45 but if it should just return 0 you just have to remove the `else if (empty($filterList) && is_array($value) && $first == "*")`condition. All values which are not arrays are just converted to int via `intval` and added to the sum. If you wanna use float then use `floatval` instead of `intval`

```
function getSum($array, $filterList = array('*')) {
    $sum = 0;
    $first = array_shift($filterList);
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == $first || $first == "*") {
            if (is_array($value) && !empty($filterList)) {
                $sum += getSum($value, $filterList);
            } else if (empty($filterList) && is_array($value)) {
                $sum += getSum($value, array("*"));
            } else if (empty($filterList)) {
                $sum += intval($value);
            }
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}

echo getSum($array,['one','*',20], 10) . "\n"; // 25
echo getSum($array,['one','*','*',20]) . "\n"; // 10
echo getSum($array,['one','*']) . "\n"; // 45
echo getSum($array) . "\n"; // 45
```

## Input Array

```
$array = array();
$array['one'] = array();
$array['one']['green'] = array();
$array['one']['green'][20] = 20;
$array['one']['blue'] = array();
$array['one']['blue'][20] = 5;
$array['one']['blue'][30] = 10;
$array['one']['orange']['red'][20] = 10;
```

## Output

Only the numbers are outputted but just added the input params for better understanding.

```
25 // (['one','*',20])
10 // (['one','*','*',20])
45 // (['one','*'])
45 // no filterList
```

Comment: This returns nothing if I just write `getSum($array)`

Comment: @lingo yeah then an error appears cause the interface is so defined. You you want to make it other just write `function getSum($array, $filterList = array())` I will add it to the code, but I think its not necessary. If the filterList is empty 0 should be returned as I understand your requirement!

Comment: @lingo Just updated it you wanted to return 45 like in your algorithm ... so I updated the code just copy and paste it again!

Comment: @lingo I am executing the code, and it works fine. Could you just paste the call of `getSum` and like you modified the header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105707/discussion-between-kordi-and-lingo).

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need a recursive function to add in wildcard "endpoints". You might as well use the same recursive nature to cover the addition as well.

The following should do what you're wanting:

```
// summing values of multidimensional array
function getSum(&$array, $path = array()){
    $sum = 0;
    if(is_int($array) and empty($path)) // return value if int
        $sum = $array;
    else if(is_array($array)){ // else add recurred values
        if(empty($path)){
            foreach($array as $value)
                $sum += getSum($value);
        } else {
            $key = array_shift($path);
            if($key=='*'){
                foreach($array as $value)
                    $sum += getSum($value, $path);
            } else {
                if(isset($array[$key]))
                    $sum += getSum($array[$key], $path);
            }
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Test:

```
$array['one'] = array();
$array['one']['green'] = array();
$array['one']['green'][20] = 20;
$array['one']['blue'] = array();
$array['one']['blue'][20] = 5;
$array['one']['blue'][30] = 10;
$array['one']['orange']['red'][20] = 10;

echo getSum($array,['one','*',20]); // 25
echo getSum($array,['one','*','*',20]); // 10
echo getSum($array,['one','*']); // 45
```

Happy coding

Comment: Is it so that I don't need `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and `RecursiveArrayIterator` anymore?

Comment: @iautomation What about `getSum($array,['one','*']);` ?

Comment: @lingo the purpose of the function is to cover the inquiry, of wildcard levels. however, as a result of already being in a recursive function, an interator is not needed.

Comment: @iautomation if `['one','*']` should not give 45 or? If yes shouldn't then `['one','*',20]` give 35?

Comment: @Kordi this is consistent functionality with the original question and code example. even though the asterisk represents one level, the integer values attained past `$path` are recursive, as the original code provided a sum via `RecursiveArrayIterator`.